# Data on the endangerment of Southwestern Mandarin?

Tags: topolect

I'm looking for some data on the endangerment of [Southwestern Mandarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southwestern_Mandarin).

Since it is rather a broad subject, it can be broken down to the [Cheng–Yu 成渝](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chengdu-Chongqing_dialect) branch as it is quite representative of the language family.

There is a section entitled [status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sichuanese_dialects#Status) on the Wikipedia page [Sichuanese dialects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sichuanese_dialects) which says:

> Though Sichuanese is not as endangered as some other languages of China, the prevalence of Sichuanese has dramatically lessened as the popularity of Standard Chinese has risen.

The endangerment claim [cites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sichuanese_dialects#cite_note-24):

> "四川经验：剽悍方言无需要保卫" (in Chinese). 新浪网新民周刊专题. Retrieved 2010-05-15.

Which links to this article: [四川经验：剽悍方言无需要保卫(图)](http://news.sina.com.cn/c/2005-05-04/17586559832.shtml), an entertainment piece which doesn't say much of anything.

---

《20世纪成都话银边研究》by 周及徐 has some interesting information on the evolution of pronunciations that clearly show the language being heavily influenced by Standard Mandarin, but it doesn't talk about endangerment.

---

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I am a native speaker of Southwestern Mandarin of Generation Z.

The new generation here often converts too many pronunciation errors of standard Mandarin into Southwestern Mandarin, or does not know some unique words. But it is far from being endangered.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).